# The inverse of this function is continuous

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I want to show that 
\begin{gather}
r:\mathopen]0,2\pi\mathclose[\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \operatorname{Im}r\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3
\\
(t,v)\mapsto \Bigl(c\cos t-v\sin t, c\sin t+v\cos t,\frac{v}{a}\Bigr)
\end{gather}
has continuous inverse.

I could try to find the expression of the inverse, but I do not see a simple way to do it.

Alternatively, I could show that $r$ is an open map: since it is bijective (I already proved this), this proves that its inverse is continuous. However, I do not know how to go about this last option.

Any hints?

Comment: I guess you mean $t \in ]0,2\pi[$, whats with $v$?

Comment: @T'x sorry... edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the [Inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) gives a convenient way to avoid explicitly calculating the inverse.